# Display too dark on an Acer emachines E725

Tags: 11.10, display

I just did a wubi install of Ubuntu 11.10 ony my acer emachines E725. After I reboot, the display is too dark that I can only see the white backgrounds and my mouse (when it is in the middle of the screen where the wallpaper is a little brighter).

Before I did a wubi install I also tried live using usb.

Does anyone know how to deal with this. Should I go ahead and do a full install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Put the cd with Ubuntu 11.10

2) Press F6 and select nomodeset

3) Select Test ubuntu and then install

4) Reboot

5) Press F6 and select nomodeset

6) Select Test ubuntu and then install

7) Open a terminal and:

$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/ubuntu

$ sudo mount ‐‐bind /dev /media/ubuntu/dev

$ sudo mount ‐‐bind /proc /media/ubuntu/proc

$ sudo mount ‐‐bind /sys /media/ubuntu/sys

$ sudo chroot /media/ubuntu

$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Edit line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"

$ sudo update-grub
$ reboot

I hope this solve your problem :)

Comment: Thank you. But I think I forgot to mention that I dual boot with windows (I did mention wubi). Anyway I kind of followed your tips and I get it to work. I followed point 1-3. Then after installing I edited /etc/default/grub as you mentioned then sudo update-grub. It works.

Comment: After much _googling_, i have found a (i think) better solution. With nomodeset, I could not change the screen resolution. I edited my /etc/default/grub with these lines `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash **acpi_osi=Linux**"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` instead of using **nomodeset**. But I have to increase the brightness (using brightness control in my laptop) to see the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Francis Lalnunmawia. Your solution is great. But if you

place `/usr/bin/setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80` in your `/etc/rc.local` file

so, your solution will be perfect.

You can see the link 
[Acer emachines e725 black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78896/acer-emachines-e725-black-screen)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to upgrade your bios, I have the same computer here.

in windows flash it directly using the exe.

if you're in linux just install freedos (1.** mega) using unetbootin and put the bios files there then start system from freedos startup disk then CD to directory dos  and run the .bat file.

enjoy.

ps : every new linux based OSes will work .

BIOS for e725 link (version 3.10) http://global-download.gateway.com/GDFiles/BIOS/BIOS/BIOS_eMachines_3.10_A_A.zip?acerid=634254114813304141&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=E%20SERIES&Step3=E725&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=EMACHINES&SC=PA_6E

  -