# Acer emachines e725 black screen

Tags: 11.10, boot-failure, acer

When i try to run system (Ubuntu 11.10) from pendrive on my laptop (Acer Emachines e725) system starts but i don't see anything (Graphic - Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller). Only black screen. Who can help me?.. :/

Comment: Why is everybody trying to use brightness settings? This could easily be a hardware or compatibility issue given Emachines' spotty compatibility(Learned the hard way through personal experience)

Answer (score 1):

You're have to place `/usr/bin/setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80` to your `/etc/rc.local` file.
You can use an external monitor to see someting for make this correction.

Note: B=XX, when XX - brightness of backlight, more digit means darker backlight.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with you. It is perfect solution. but you need add more thing,
see the following link

[Display too dark on an Acer emachines E725](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65944/display-too-dark-on-an-acer-emachines-e725)

Comment: Please summarize the main points here when you give a link.